# Appending and removing multiple elements with jquery included

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have this code

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('1');
name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('span.one');
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class ="' + x + '" ><br><input type="text" class= "' + x + '" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br></div>'); //add input box
      $('.hello:last').after('<div class="hello" id = "' + x + '"   >Hello, <span class="name"></span><br><br></div>');

      $('input').on('input', function(e) {

        divtoappend = $(this).attr('class');
        var val = "";
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sel = "#" + divtoappend + " span";
        $(sel).text('');
        $(sel).append(val);
      });

    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    var rem = $(this).parents('div').attr('class');
    $('#' + rem).remove();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add member</button>
  <br><br>
  <div><input type="text" id="1" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hello" id="1">

  Hello, <span class="one"></span><br><br>

</div>
```

You can type your name and it will appear below automatically. You can add more "members" and type their name and the same will happen. It works fine.

Now, I tried to make it with 3 inputs per group and make a single phrase using those 3 inputs. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/JBxnQ/165/

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('name');
name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('span.one');
  console.log(this.value);
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});

var name1 = document.getElementById('city');
name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('span.two');
  console.log(this.value);
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});

var name1 = document.getElementById('age');
name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('span.three');
  console.log(this.value);
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  var y = 2;
  var z = 3;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x, y, z < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      y++;
      z++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class ="' + x + '" ><label>Name</label><input type="text" class= "' + x + '" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br></div><div class ="' + y + '" ><label>City</label><input type="text" class= "' + y + '" name="mytext[]"/> <br> </div> <div class ="' + z + '" ><label>Age</label><input type="text" class= "' + z + '" name="mytext[]"/> <br> </div>'); //add input box
      $('.hello:last').append('<div class="hello" id = "' + x + '"   >Hello, <span class="one"></span></div><div class="hello" id = "' + y + '"   >, from <span class="two"></span></div><div class="hello" id = "' + z + '"   >. Your age is: <span class="three"></span><br><br></div>');

      $('input').on('input', function(e) {

        divtoappend = $(this).attr('class');
        var val = "";
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sel = "#" + divtoappend + " span";
        $(sel).text('');
        $(sel).append(val);
      });

    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    var rem = $(this).parents('div').attr('class');
    $('#' + rem).remove();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    y--;
    z--;
  });


});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}

span.add,
span.remove {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <br><br>
  <label>Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="mytext[]"> <br>
  <label>City</label><input type="text" id="city" name="mytext[]"> <br>
  <label>Age</label><input type="text" id="age" name="mytext[]">
</div>
<br>
<div class="hello" id="1">

  Hello, <span class="one"></span>, from <span class="two"></span>. Your age is: <span class="three"></span><br><br>

</div>
```

In this last code, the first "group of inputs" works perfectly. My problem comes with the second one ("first added member"): it won't make the phrase in a single line (i tried with display:inline inside the divs but didn't work).

If you add a third group of inputs ("add a third member") it gets worse (you'll see)

I need all the other added "group of inputs" work exactly as the first one.

Comment: Having multiple elements with duplicate `id`s in the same document is invalid HTML - it makes selecting harder than it needs to be, you should fix that.

Comment: plus, you may not need ids at all if you store newly created element.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS is generating a different DOM to your initial one in the HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="hello" id="1">
  Hello, <span class="one"></span>, from <span class="two"></span>. Your age is: 
  <span class="three"></span><br><br>
</div>
```

But your JS is creating this:

```
<div class="hello" id = "x"   >
  Hello, 
  <span class="one"></span>
</div>
<div class="hello" id = "y"   >
  , from <span class="two"></span>
</div>
<div class="hello" id = "z"   >
  . Your age is: 
  <span class="three"></span><br><br>
</div>
```

You need to remove all the classes and just have the same DOM.

```
$('.hello:last').append('<div class="hello" id = "' + i + '"   >Hello, <span class="one"></span>, from <span class="two"></span>. Your age is: <span class="three"></span><br><br></div>');
```

I'm also a little confused as to why you have x y z vars. You should be able to achieve this with a single variable that you just increment each time you add a new group. It will also make it possible to create unlimited groups, you can also limit it by just checking that incrementing var when you're creating a group.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really noob with this. Can you explain this better, please? I would thank you a lot. If you add some code for reference would be great